# How do you write an odbc.ini file with configured ssh tunelling?

Tags: macos, ssh, odbc, mysql-connector, apple-m1

I'm on m1 mac, with tableau 2021.4, and as a result I'm forced to used the iodbc.org SDK. The app doesn't work or register drivers meant for the m1 mac so I've used the intel x86_64 mysql odbc driver. I'm not asking tableau support for reasons.

The mysql db I need to connect to is on a server I can't connect to directly (behind a vpc) and an ssh tunneling works sometimes within tableau. This link is the closest one to my problem. [tableau_support](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000bhTkmSAE/error-connecting-to-mysql-error-code-b19090e0). Regardless, The connection keeps dropping and I'm guessing it's due to the odbc.ini file being configured incorrectly.

Ive been referring to this as it's the closest thing to help me figure this out: [iodbc](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/doc/iodbc/wiki/iodbcWiki/ODBCMacOSX)  but I'm at my wits end.

My odbc.ini file:

```
[connection_name]
Driver = /usr/local/mysql-connector-odbc-8.0.20-macos10.15-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc8w.so
Username = db_username
Database = db_name
Port = 3306
Server = db_name.xyz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Hostname = ec2-##-##-##-##.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

How can I write a mysql odbc.ini file with the correct parameters to set up an ssh tunnel or to work with an ssh tunnel?

As an addition, the db itself is not on localhost, it has its own different endpoint and I need to use a pem file to gain access to the server the db is hosted on.

...

Answer (score 0):

What about creating SSH-Tunnel, similar to this?

```
ssh myaccount@db_server -L 9002:localhost:3306
```

Then connect to port 9002 on m1-localhost this will be forwarded to db_server.
If port 3306 isn't used on your m1, you can use it to simplify:

```
ssh myaccount@db_server -L 3306:localhost:3306 -N
```

Details: `man ssh`

Or simplified: http://lifesim.de/lex/ssh.html

Comment: I was using this method but the connection kept dropping and having numerous problems though the connection (with tunneling) worked fine in dbeaver.